# Em PHP o que esta tag <?= ?> representa?

Tags: php

Em PHP o que esta tag representa ?

**Tag de abertura:**

```
<?=
```

**Tag de fechamento:**

```
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esta sintaxe é um atalho para isto:

```
<?php echo  ; ?>
```

Antes do PHP 5.4 a opção [short tags](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) deveria estar habilitada para poder se usar este atalho. No PHP 5.4 essa opção passou a estar sempre disponível.

Tanto é que essa sintaxe é especificada na **[documentação do echo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php)**.

Exemplo:

```
<p>Meu nome é <?=$nome?></p>
```

equivale a

```
<p>Meu nome é <?php echo $nome; ?></p>
```

Antes desta mudança do PHP 5.4, o uso do `echo` implícito era problemático, pois as tags curtas de abertura `<? ?>`se confundiam com instruções XML, e normalmente as hospedagens em geral mantém essa opção desligada.

Como o sinal de `=` serviria em teoria para desambiguação nestes casos, resolveu-se habilitar esta opção separadamente da configuração das tags curtas.

Answer (score 3):

*Esta diretiva também afeta a forma abreviada `<?=` anteriores ao PHP 5.4.0, que é a mesma que `<? echo`. Para uso desta abreviatura é necessário que short_open_tag esteja ativo. Desde PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` está sempre disponível.*

Referência de: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag