# Erro em versões mais novas

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli

Tenho essa linha no servidor que usa PHP e MYSQL em versões anteriores do que em minha máquina local, funciona perfeitamente no servidor, porém em minha máquina com versões mais atuais não funciona.

Existe algum problema com essa linha nas versões mais atuais do PHP?

```
<? echo $i++."<font color='blue'>...</font>".$linha['numero_contrato']."<font size='1' face='Verdana' color='blue'>.".$linha['apelido']."</font>"; ?>
```

Comment: O idela é usar `<?php` no de `<?` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103178/91

Comment: E não utilizar mais o elemento `font` do HTML, ele já está obsoleto há muito tempo.

Comment: Ok amigo, realmente usar <?php no lugar de <? resolveu o problema...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código está utilizando short_open_tags

- https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Isso pode ser modificado no php.ini ou .user.ini do seu projeto.

Ou para normalizar as coisas inicie com `<?php` ao invés de `<?`

Comment: Muito Obrigado Rafael. Informação bastante relevante!