# campos input hidden do html não saem no $_POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho seguinte `jQuery`

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#contato").on("submit", function () {

    var formData = new FormData(this); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "_requeridos/emailAcompanha.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            beforeSend: function() {            
               $("div.conversa div form div.contatoBaixo .btnAcesso").css('display', 'none');
               $("div.conversa div form div.contatoBaixo img").css('display', 'block');            
            },
            success: function (retorno) {

               $("div.conversa div form div.contatoBaixo .btnAcesso").css('display', 'block');
               $("div.conversa div form div.contatoBaixo img").css('display', 'none');

                if (retorno == "OK") {
                  resposta = "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
                } else {
                  resposta = "Erro no envio do E-mail";
                }
               $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
               $(".resposta").html(resposta);    
               //refresh na página após 1 segundo
              // setTimeout(window.location.reload(),1000);

            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

    return false;

  }); 

});
```

E o `form`

```
<form id="contato"> 

   <input type="hidden" id="idEmail" value="<?php echo $_GET["idEmail"]; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" id="adminCli" value="c" /> 

    <textarea placeholder="Descrição" class="textarea" name="descricao" id="descricao" cols="80" rows="15"></textarea><br /> <br /> 

    <div class="contatoBaixo"> 
       <img src="_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif" style="display:none;" />
       <input name="envia" class="btnAcesso" type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
    </div>

 </form>
```

E o `php`

```
<?php

    require_once "../_controles/_conexao/Conexao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/EmailsDao.php";

    $connection = new Conexao(); 
    $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();

    $emailDao = new EmailsDao($conexao);

print "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);    
print "</pre>";


    $gravarResposta = $emailDao->responder($_POST["idEmail"], $_POST["descricao"], $_POST["adminCli"]);

    echo $gravarResposta ? "OK" : "ERRO";

?>
```

Ao imprimir:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);    
print "</pre>";
```

Os campos `input hidden` do `html` não saem no `$_POST`

Porque?

A saída no **inspector do navegador** é

```
Array
(
    [descricao] => teste
)
```

Comment: Já tentou definir a propriedade `name` deles?

Comment: Obra do acaso? Não! Obra do cansaço! Obrigado. Se postar como resposta eu a aceito!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seus campos *hidden* não possuem a propriedade `name` definida:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idEmail" value="<?php echo $_GET["idEmail"]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="adminCli" value="c" />
```

Fora isso, as aspas em `value` do primeiro campo não estão escapadas, o que poderá gerar efeitos colaterais na sua aplicação - ou no próprio editor. Além disso, ao invés de `<?php echo`, você pode utilizar a forma simplificada `<?=`:

```
<input name="email" type="hidden" id="idEmail" value="<?= $_GET['idEmail'] ?>" />
```

[Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/5878)

[Em PHP o que esta tag <?= ?> representa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103178/5878)

Comment: impressão de valores

Comment: @CarlosRocha Não entendi seu comentário.

Comment: kkk, resposta a tua pergunta no final da tua resposta: Em PHP o que esta tag <?= ?> representa?

Comment: @CarlosRocha mas não foi uma pergunta, mas sim um link para a pergunta que trata disso :D

Comment: por padrão  Short Tag estabeleço desativado

Comment: @CarlosRocha `<?=` não é uma short tag, apenas `<?` é.